# debugging info for vsyscall and vdso

Tags: debugging, perf, vdso

I'm using perf tool to profile a kernel module on centos 6.5 (kernel version: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64). I've installed the kernel debug info packages separately. While I am able to see the list of [kernel.kallsyms] functions, the symbols related to [vdso] and [vsyscall] can not be recognized and are shown as hex numbers.

Any ideas how the debugging info for these two libraries can be added?